# Backquote without parens

Tags: macros, clojure, common-lisp

I am working through the excellent book Let Over Lambda, and I am trying to port the Common Lisp code for defunits over to Clojure.

The following generates a macro that is supposed to take

```
(defn defunits-chaining [u units prev]
  (if (some #(= u %) prev)
    (throw (Throwable. (str u " depends on " prev))))
  (let [spec (first (filter #(= u (first %)) units))]
    (if (nil? spec)
      (throw (Throwable. (str "unknown unit " u)))
      (let [chain (second spec)]
        (if (list? chain)
          (* (first chain)
             (defunits-chaining
               (second chain)
               units
               (cons u prev)))
          chain)))))

(defmacro defunits [quantity base-unit & units]
  `(defmacro ~(symbol (str "unit-of-" quantity))
     [valu# un#]
     `(* ~valu#
         ~(case un#
           ~base-unit 1
            ~@(map (fn [x]
                     `(~(first x)               ;; <-- PRETTY SURE IT'S THIS `(
                       ~(defunits-chaining
                          (first x)
                          (cons `(~base-unit 1)
                                (partition 2 units))
                          nil)))
                   (partition 2 units))))))

(defunits time s m 60 h 3600)
```

and turn it into a macro that can be called like

```
(unit-of-time 4 h)
```

and give the results in the base unit (seconds in this case). I think is the problem is a Clojure/CL api change in "case". "Case" in CL looks like this:

```
(case 'a (('b) 'no) (('c) 'nope) (('a) 'yes))
```

but in clojure...

```
(case 'a 'b 'no 'c 'nope 'a 'yes)
```

HOW CONVENIENT. I changed my anon function in the nested defmacro, but it keeps generating like

```
(case un#
  s 1
  (m 60)
  (h 3600)
```

How can I prevent those outer parens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change your `map` to `mapcat`.

```
(defmacro defunits [quantity base-unit & units]
  `(defmacro ~(symbol (str "unit-of-" quantity))
     [valu# un#]
     `(* ~valu#
         ~(case un#
            ~base-unit 1
            ~@(mapcat (fn [x] ;; <----- mapcat instead of map is the only change
                        `(~(first x)
                          ~(defunits-chaining
                             (first x)
                             (cons `(~base-unit 1)
                                   (partition 2 units))
                             nil)))
                      (partition 2 units))))))
```

To elaborate, and respond to the currently-accepted answer: `flatten` is never, never, never right (with rare exceptions for use by experts only). At best it's a band-aid that will get you the right results for simple inputs but fail on complex inputs. Instead, it is usually right to use `apply concat` to flatten a list by one level, or use `mapcat` instead of `map` to generate an already-flatter list, or perhaps something more involved and specialized for a particularly convoluted data structure. Here, a simple `mapcat` is all that is needed.

I suppose I should note that the `defunits` macro's inputs are so tightly constrained (they really must be symbols and numbers), in practice there will be no input that `flatten` will produce the wrong output for. But flatten is a bad habit to get into, and results in longer, more complicated code anyway.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for earlier.  I guess I need to do some digging around in the clojure standard functions.

Comment: Yeah, looking at the question again, this is *the* correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

If you wrap your map in a flatten, it should produce the results your looking for.

```
(defmacro defunits [quantity base-unit & units]
  `(defmacro ~(symbol (str "unit-of-" quantity))
     [valu# un#]
     `(* ~valu#
         ~(case un#
           ~base-unit 1
            ~@(flatten ;; <- changed this
                (map (fn [x]
                       `(~(first x)
                         ~(defunits-chaining
                            (first x)
                            (cons `(~base-unit 1)
                                  (partition 2 units))
                            nil)))
                   (partition 2 units)))))))
```

What's going on:  In your initial implementation, your map is returning something a list of lists when what you need is a list of atoms.  [Flatten](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/flatten) takes an arbitrarily deep list of lists and turns it into a single list of values.

Another approach would be to use a [reduce](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/reduce) rather than a map:

```
(defmacro defunits [quantity base-unit & units]
  `(defmacro ~(symbol (str "my-unit-of-" quantity))
     [valu# un#]
     `(* ~valu#
         ~(case un#
           ~base-unit 1
            ~@(reduce (fn [x y] ;; <- reduce instead of map
                        (concat x ;; <- use concat to string the values together
                              `(~(first y)
                                ~(defunits-chaining
                                   (first y)
                                   (cons `(~base-unit 1)
                                         (partition 2 units))
                                   nil))))
                      '()
                      (partition 2 units))))))
```

This would avoid creating the list of lists in the first place as reduce rolls up all the passed in values into a single result.

Better yet, (Thanks to [amalloy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/625403/amalloy) for spotting this one), there's [mapcat](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/mapcat):

```
(defmacro defunits [quantity base-unit & units]
  `(defmacro ~(symbol (str "unit-of-" quantity))
     [valu# un#]
     `(* ~valu#
         ~(case un#
            ~base-unit 1
            ~@(mapcat (fn [x] ;; <----- mapcat instead of map is the only change
                        `(~(first x)
                          ~(defunits-chaining
                             (first x)
                             (cons `(~base-unit 1)
                                   (partition 2 units))
                             nil)))
                      (partition 2 units))))))
```

Mapcat effectively does the same thing as the reduce version but implicitly handles the concat for you.

Comment: Yep, ~@(flatten (map (fn [x]
did it just fine, I am not sure how I missed that in the hundred things I tried. *head smack*

Answer (score 3):

You can concatenate the parenthesized pairs (using, say, `apply concat`) or **use amalloy's answer** (the best idea).

You could also construct your return form using seq functions:

```
(defmacro defunits [...]
  (let [macro-name (symbol ...)
        valsym (gensym "val__")
        unitsym (gensym "unit__")]
    (list `defmacro             ; using ` so the symbol gets ns-qualified
          macro-name
          [valsym unitsym]
          (make-body-expression ...)))) ; define appropriately
```

I think this makes sense here, since you end up unquoting pretty much everything anyway, with two levels of syntax-quote; it is largely a matter of taste though.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, this is going to take me a day or two to puzzle out. I didn't know you could construct it from a seq, that is really cool. This is very well thought out, thanks so much.

Comment: Macros are just appropriately-registered (with the compiler) functions returning list structure. Backquote / syntax-quote with unquoting is just one possible way of producing list structure. Each one can be used (and useful) without the other (although I believe in Clojure I find myself using syntax-quote outside of macros less often than I would use backquote in Scheme).

Comment: Edited to indicate I think amalloy's answer is the most deserving of the green tick. I'd still prefer unwrapping one level of syntax-quote, so I'll leave this answer in place for this suggestion.